# C# Random number generator, to display in MessageBox

Tags: c#, arrays, random, console-application

I'm trying to create a random number generator,  ranging from 1 to 1000 for 100 times to achieve the following results on both Console App and popup Windows Message Box (MessageBox.Show) in this format:

- 100 random numbers in order from smallest to largest
- Amount of even numbers generated
- Smallest number generated
- Largest number generated
- The range of numbers

I'm confused at creating the array to store the value and getting the amount of even numbers generated with what I have here, say for example my array name would be "array" and to store the numbers with "n"

```
string [] array = {item};
string output = string.Join("\n", array);
MessageBox.Show(output)
```

This is my code, how do I add this in?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NumberGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random number = new Random();
            int min = int.MaxValue,
            max = int.MinValue;

            for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
            {
                int n = number.Next(0, 999);
                Console.WriteLine(n);

                if (n < min)
                    min = n;
                if (n > max)
                    max = n;
            }

            int range = min - max + 1;

            string[] array = { "Minimum number is (min)" };
            string output = string.Join("\n", array);
            Console.WriteLine("Minimum number = {0}, Maximum number = {1}, Range = {2}", min, max, range);
            MessageBox.Show(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking 100 numbers from 1->1.000. In this way, you may have 10/% duplicates. Are you concerned about this?

Comment: @XristosK nope, that is not what I'm concerned about

Comment: If you are looking for a truly random numbers, you should be using RNGCryptoServiceProvider class to generate them rather than using Random class

Comment: @J.Tuc I just need to output 100 different numbers, need not be so unique, preferrably with this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.
Code should be self expanatory

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random number = new Random();
    int rangeFrom = 0;
    int rangeTo = 999;
    List<int> generatedNumbers = new List<int>();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
    {
        generatedNumbers.Add(number.Next(rangeFrom, rangeTo));

    }

    generatedNumbers.Sort();

    string output = "generated numbers: {0} \r\n\rmin: {1}\r\n\r\nmax: {2}\r\n\r\nrange: {3}-{4}";
    output = string.Format(output,
        string.Join(", ", generatedNumbers.ToArray()),
        generatedNumbers.Min(),
        generatedNumbers.Max(),
        rangeFrom,
        rangeTo);


    MessageBox.Show(output);
}
```

to summarize:
I have used List for easier manipulation of data and used Linq (make sure you have `using System.Linq;` in your app).

Comment: You meant to write `generatedNumbers.Max()` for the fourth `string.Format(...)` parameter, didn't you?

Comment: This helped. Thank you :)

Comment: @user7605572 best way to say thanks is to mark mark replay as an answer :) glad I could help